# How to change href using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, href

I have a button, that when a user clicks on it, The page will be redirected to another link.

Index.html:

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search"
  id="input-box"
  autocomplete="off"
  style="width: 250px;">
<button id="submitbtn"
        onClick="submitClicked"
        href="">
</button>
</input>
```

Script.js:

```
document.getElementById("submitbtn").onclick = function() {submitBtn()};

  function submitBtn() {
    for(let i=0; i<availableKeywords.length; i++){
      if (result == availableKeywords[i]){ //checks if the result(inputted by the user) is matched with the keyword
        document.getElementById("submitbtn").href = "/index2.html?key=${availableKey[i]}" //How do i make this work?
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` does not have `href` property inherently but you can set it as an attribute.

```
document.getElementById("submitbtn").setAttribute("href", `/index2.html?key=${availableKey[i]}`);
```

I probably should point out that this will not automatically redirect though.

To do a redirect, you can use `window.location.href` instead.

Replace your button update code with this.

```
window.location.href = `/index2.html?key=${availableKey[i]}`
```

Comment: How do i automatically redirect it?

Answer (score 0):

**Comments**

1. Html input tags do not have closing tags.
2. You do not have to set onclick in javascript if you have an onclick in html.

**HTML**

```html
<input id="input-box" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" style="width: 250px;">
<button id="submit-btn" onclick="submitClicked(this)">Submit</button>
```

**JS**

```js
const availableKeywords = [];

function submitClicked() {
  const input = document.getElementById('input-box');
  const value = input.value ?? null;

  for (const keyword of availableKeywords || []) {
    if ( value != keyword ) continue;
    location.href = `${location.origin}/index2.html?key=${keyword}`;
    break;
  }
}
```